# All objects refuse to save c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am confused why my checkbox states are not saving. I have done this before on other projects, am I missing some bit of code?

[image]

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            materialCheckBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox1;
            materialCheckBox2.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox2;
            materialCheckBox4.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox3;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox1 = materialCheckBox1.Checked;
            Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox2 = materialCheckBox2.Checked;
            Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox3 = materialCheckBox4.Checked;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

Comment: Can you look for some error/message in debug/output window if you can run this in VS? Also, try putting another setting (like string) and see if that gets saved or not.

Comment: There are no error messages in the debugger. And there is no runtime error. It simply refuses to save. But I will try a string right now.

Comment: The string did not save either...

Comment: Are you sure that the FormClosing event is executed?

Comment: And here I take a walk of shame. My exit button was Environment.Exit(0)...

Comment: :) don't worry we all have been there!

Answer (score 3):

I was using `Environment.Exit(0);` to close instead of `Application.Exit();`

Why does this occur?

`System.Environment.Exit()`: Terminates the current process and gives the underlying operating system the specified exit code.

This does NOT Save!

`System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit()`: Informs all message loops that they must terminate, and then closes all application windows after the messages have been processed.

- https://thestandardoutput.com/posts/terminating-your-c-application/

Comment: For the sake of others who may find this question in the future, can you expand on this answer with documentation on why `Envrionment.Exit(0)` was not the way to go?